# Bootstrap Datepicker Formatting

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootstrap-datepicker. The datepicker works, but looks like this:

[image: how it appears when run]

Only the datepicker is affected. Other elements (buttons, labels, etc.) appear with standard bootstrap formatting. This is the case on both my local server and on IE 9.

I am not changing any of the datepicker's parameters or doing anything fancy:

```
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

Full jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4KbV6/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using chrome, and the fiddle link looks as I would expect it to. Is there a JS setting perhaps toggled on your local server and machine that would be causing this?

Comment: You are correct. I am using a WebSphere server and a setting removed several of my imports. I downloaded the appropriate .css files and the formatting issue went away.